# Translating Apple Sample "Complex Multi-Touch Handling" Code into Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cfdictionary

[This website](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/multitouch_background/multitouch_background.html) describes what I want to achieve under the 'Handling a Complex Multitouch Sequence' section. Unfortunately, it is shown in Objective-C. I can translate most of it into Swift, but when it comes to a few lines, like the lines with `CFDictionary`, I honestly have no idea what's going on.

If somebody could help me understand/translate listings 3-4 and 3-5 or suggest another method for handling multi-touch events, I would be very grateful. I have left '???' where I am not sure.

Here is the Obj-C (storing touch initial location):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     [self cacheBeginPointForTouches:touches];
}

- (void)cacheBeginPointForTouches:(NSSet *)touches {
    if ([touches count] > 0) {
        for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
            CGPoint *point = (CGPoint *)CFDictionaryGetValue(touchBeginPoints, touch);
            if (point == NULL) {
                point = (CGPoint *)malloc(sizeof(CGPoint));
                CFDictionarySetValue(touchBeginPoints, touch, point);
            }
            *point = [touch locationInView:view.superview];
        }
    }
}
```

Here is retrieving the initial location:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     CGAffineTransform newTransform = [self incrementalTransformWithTouches:touches];
}

- (CGAffineTransform)incrementalTransformWithTouches:(NSSet *)touches {
     NSArray *sortedTouches = [[touches allObjects] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compareAddress:)];

     // Other code here
     CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

     UITouch *touch1 = [sortedTouches objectAtIndex:0];
     UITouch *touch2 = [sortedTouches objectAtIndex:1];

     CGPoint beginPoint1 = *(CGPoint *)CFDictionaryGetValue(touchBeginPoints, touch1);
     CGPoint currentPoint1 = [touch1 locationInView:view.superview];
     CGPoint beginPoint2 = *(CGPoint *)CFDictionaryGetValue(touchBeginPoints, touch2);
     CGPoint currentPoint2 = [touch2 locationInView:view.superview];


     // Compute the affine transform
     return transform;
}
```

Here's what I've managed:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    cacheBeginPoint(touches: touches)
}

func cacheBeginPoint(touches: Set<UITouch>) {
    if touches.count > 0 {
        for touch: UITouch in touches {
            var point: CGPoint? = CFDictionaryGetValue(???)
            if point == nil {
                point = ???
                CFDictionarySetValue(???)
            }
            point = touch.location(in: view?.superview)
        }
    }
}
```

and:

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
    var newTransform: CGAffineTransform = incrementalTransform(touches: touches)
}

func incrementalTransform(touches: Set<UITouch>) -> CGAffineTransform {
    var sortedTouches: NSArray = ???
    var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity

    var touch1: UITouch? = sortedTouches[0]
    var touch2: UITouch? = sortedTouches[1]

    var beginPoint1: = CFDictionaryGetValue(???)
    var currentPoint1: = touch1?.location(in: view?.superview)
    var beginPoint2: = CFDictionaryGetValue(???)
    var currentPoint2: = touch2?.location(in: view?.superview)

    return transform
}
```

Comment: Do necessary need to use Swift? Why not just use Obj-C code as is?

Comment: I'm afraid I do not know how to use Obj-C. Once this code is in Swift, I will be able to manipulate it and integrate it into the rest of my code.

Comment: You can safely use Obj-C classes inside Swift project. More info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html